# getPrimaryKey function in YII 1 is not working

Tags: php, yii

How should i get last inserted id through getPrimaryKey() in YII 1?

My record is inserted in database but it returning me empty value.

I have used below code.

```
public function saveSurvey($model){ 
    if($model->ID == ''){
        $model->Name = trim($model->Name);
        $model->EngagementQuestionNo = trim($model->EngagementQuestionNo);
        $model->CSVColumnCount = trim($model->CSVColumnCount);
        $model->LocationQuestionNo = trim($model->LocationQuestionNo);
        $model->CreatedOn = new CDbExpression('NOW()');         
        if($model->save()){
            echo 'saved id >> ';
            echo $surveyID  = $model->ID;
        }
        else{
            echo 'error';
        }
   }
}
```

My current rules in Model

```
public function rules()
{       
    return array(
        array('Name,EngagementQuestionNo,CSVColumnCount,LocationQuestionNo', 'required'),
        array('CSVColumnCount', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('Name', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        array('QuestionNumbers, ID', 'safe'),
        array('ID, Name, CreatedOn, LastModifiedOn,QuestionNumbers', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Comment: I think you need use `$model->ID `instead of`$model->primaryKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just initialize the new object of Survey model class

**$newObjectModel = new Survey();**

After adding of new object you code look like below:

```
    public function saveSurvey($model){ 
    if($model->ID == ''){
        $newObjectModel = new Survey(); 
        $newObjectModel ->Name = trim($model->Name);
        $newObjectModel ->EngagementQuestionNo = trim($model->EngagementQuestionNo);
        $newObjectModel ->CSVColumnCount = trim($model->CSVColumnCount);
        $newObjectModel ->LocationQuestionNo = trim($model->LocationQuestionNo);
        $newObjectModel ->CreatedOn = new CDbExpression('NOW()');         
        if($newObjectModel ->save()){
            echo $surveyID  = $newObjectModel ->ID;
        }
        else{
            echo 'error';
        }
   }
}
```